# Как без боли и страданий задеплоить на томкат 9 веб-сервис на java 11, работающий по soap?

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, веб-служба, java-11

Написал сервис - веб-клиент, работающий по soap, написал его на 11-ой джаве. Сначала не мог найти нужную библиотеку для soap и веб-сервисов. В итоге остановился на таких:

```
<dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
```

Выкидываю из сервиса почти все библиотеки (кроме внутренних). Все библиотеки в виде джарников кидаю в директорию lib томката. И при деплое пишет следующие ошибки:

```
...
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\hk2-core.jar
...
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\class-model.jar
...
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\config.jar
...
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\auto-depends.jar
...
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\javax.inject.jar
...
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\hk2-api.jar
...
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\osgi-resource-locator.jar
....
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\tiger-types.jar
...
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\bean-validator.jar
...
 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\lib\jtype.jar
...
```

Пробовал искать эти библиотеки в интернете, но это довольно трудоемко. Нашёл что-то, вставил в папку lib, но он всё равно писал эти ошибки. Потом заметил, что имена джарников не совпадают - у меня ещё версии были дописаны. Но имена менять не стал: уже не уверен, что это правильный путь, да и тоже довольно нудно и трудоемко.

[image: Библиотеки, которые я кладу в папку lib]

Comment: использовать Spring boot вместе с maven/gradle, там Tomcat уже установлен и настроен, сервер подымется без каких-либо усилий. Собирать что-то вручную, когда есть такие шикарные инструменты - просто бессмысленно.

Comment: @coolsv Согласен, но у нас в фирме никто не готов к этому, а я один не смогу это продавить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путём долгого поиска в интернете выяснил, что это не ошибки, и они ни на что не влияют. Отключается добавлением `<JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>`
 в `context.xml` (внутрь`<Context>... </Context>`)